# Im trying to display album art within the listview, but having issues

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, media-player, mediastore

Im able to successfully display album art on my now playing screen, but not through the listview using the same code, the only difference really, is that its being run through an adapter class, like the artist name and title are to display it for each item in the list

Listview class

```
 public void getSongList() {
    //query external audio
    ContentResolver musicResolver = getContentResolver();
    // Uri musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "!=0";
    String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER;
    Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(uriMusicShow, null, selection, null, sortOrder);

    //iterate over results if valid
    if (musicCursor != null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        //get columns
        int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
        int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
        int artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
        Long albumId = musicCursor.getLong(musicCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));
        Bitmap artwork=null;

        Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
        Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, albumId);


        //add songs to list
        do {
            long thisId = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
            String thisTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
            String thisArtist = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);

            try {
                artwork = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(musicResolver, uri);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            songList.add(new Song(thisTitle, thisArtist, thisId, artwork));
        }
        while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

Adapter Class

```
public class SongAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

//song list and layout
public ArrayList<Song> songs;
private LayoutInflater songInf;

//constructor
public SongAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Song> theSongs){
    songs=theSongs;
    songInf= LayoutInflater.from(c);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return songs.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    return 0;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //map to song layout
    RelativeLayout songLay = (RelativeLayout)songInf.inflate(R.layout.song_item, parent, false);
    //get title and artist views
    TextView songView = (TextView)songLay.findViewById(R.id.song_title);
    TextView artistView = (TextView)songLay.findViewById(R.id.song_artist);
 //   ImageView albumView = (ImageView)songLay.findViewById(R.id.album_cover);
    //get song using position
    Song currSong = songs.get(position);
    //get title and artist strings
    songView.setText(currSong.getTitle());
    artistView.setText(currSong.getArtist());
 //   albumView.setImageBitmap(currSong.getArt());
    //set position as tag
    songLay.setTag(position);
    return songLay; }}
```

And the separate class

```
public class Song {
private long id;
private String title;
private String artist;
private Bitmap art;


public Song(String songTitle,String songArtist,long songID, Bitmap albumArt){
    id=songID;
    title=songTitle;
    artist=songArtist;
    art=albumArt;
}


public long getID(){return id;}
public String getTitle(){return title;}
public String getArtist(){return artist;}
public Bitmap getArt(){return art;}}
```

im not sure why its not displaying what it needs to display, any help would be great, thank you

Comment: Is there a reason artistView.setImagebitmap() is commented out?

Comment: that was a mistake, but still even with them not commented out, i still dont have any result, i get
08-24 16:51:16.212  25239-25239/com.example.mason.mediaplayer W/System.err﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: No entry for content://media/external/audio/albumart/4

Comment: Just want a little clarification, so the listview is being made but what happens? Does it only not display the image?  And everything else shows or does nothing work.?

Comment: Yes, everything else works perfectly, except for the image, I have a background on the image for testing, and the background comes through just fine, but the image for the album art does not appear

Comment: you might be getting an exception while trying to load the art work and it stays NULL, debug and see there is an exception or not.